# How to chose specific folder to save custom screenshot to for each screenshot?

Tags: directory, customization, screenshot, default

I am on **ElementaryOS.**

To make it simple, I use the shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Print</kbd>, which allows you to take a custom screenshot (you chose the area of your screen you want to save). I **do not** want to change the default folder screenshots are saved to. Instead, I would like to chose for each screenshot I take. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use the **scrot** utility to take screenshots. Just pass the full path of the file to be saved in the command line.

You have a number of useful options: you can choose to capture the whole desktop or just the window that has the focus. If you want to manually select the area to capture use the `-s` option.

So it's quite easy to automate captures and you could even run `scrot` minimized in a loop with a delay between each capture to speed up your work.

It even does thumbnails and you can also pipe another command.

[Scrot: A Command Line Tool to Take Desktop/Server Screenshots Automatically in Linux](https://www.tecmint.com/take-screenshots-in-linux-using-scrot/)